# OpenShift Pro - PostgreSql Restore Failure

Tags: postgresql, openshift, pg-restore

I am trying to restore a PostgreSQL database on OpenShift Pro.

The backup file is 72mb, the database is 155 tables, so it's not huge but it's not small either.

The restore command:

**pg_restore  --dbname=mmjdb --verbose --no-owner --role=mmj 17.09.21.backup**

It runs for a while and seems to be working but then it stops. The terminal shows:-

> pg_restore: processing data for table "public.bookingdatehouraudit"
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly
>           This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>           before or while processing the request.
>
> sh-4.2$ command terminated with exit code 137

I have given the deployment 2GiB Memory.
I have the Persistent Volume Claim postgresql as 1GiB capacity.

I'm guessing that it's running out of resources...

I had no problems restoring this database on OpenShift 2.

Any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Can you confirm where you are running the command? Are you using ``oc rsync`` to load the dump file into the container or a persistent volume and using ``oc rsh`` to access the database container and run the restore command, or are you using port forwarding to expose the database port to your local machine and running the restore using a local client? Also, are you looking at the database logs and are there any errors there?

Comment: I used oc rsync to put the file into <postgresql-pod_name>:/var/lib/pgsql/data. Then I used oc rsh <postgresql-pod_name> to start a remote shell. Then I used cd /var/lib/pgsql/data/mmjdb to change folder. Then I ran the restore using the command above. Where will I find logs? I cannot oc rsh onto the pod it gives an error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("postgresql")

Comment: I have just added postgresql to the project. How do I add extra storage to it?

Comment: You can use ``oc logs`` on the name of the pod, or see logs under pod in web console. I don't understand comment 'cannot oc rsh onto pod', didn't you have that working to run the restore command, or is that after it it fails to restore.

Comment: As to adding extra storage, do you mean resizing the volume you already added? If you use the PostrgreSQL (persistent) template from the catalog it will add storage and template should allow you to specify size of storage. You obviously need to have added storage from account.manage.com to your account if on Pro.

Comment: I have managed to get the database running, I used 2GiB memory and 2GiB storage. Subsequently I reduced memory to 1GiB and it all seems ok. Once again, thanks for your help Graham, I'm nearly there...